# OpenERP tree view not showing correctly

Tags: xml, odoo

There is something wrong with my tree view and I couldn't identify it. Please help me to solve this since this is not look like original Openerp Tree view. I can not see search area and other formatting in that.

[image]

**XML**

```
 <record id="view_hr_mnthly_evaluation_search" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.mnthly.evaluation.search</field>
        <field name="model">hr.mnthly.evaluation</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Monthly Evaluation">
                <field name="employee_id" />

                <separator/>
                <filter icon="terp-check" domain="[('state','=','draft')]" string="To Submit" name="to_submit"/>
                <filter icon="terp-camera_test" domain="[('state','=','confirm')]" string="To Acknowledge" name="to_ackn"/>
                <filter icon="terp-camera_test" domain="[('state','=','validate')]" string="Submitted to HR" name="in_hr"/>
                <filter icon="terp-camera_test" domain="[('state','in',('confirm','validate1','validate'))]" string="Submitted by Employee" name="out_emp"/>

            </search>
        </field>
    </record>



 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_hr_mnthly_evaluation_submitted_tree">
        <field name="name">hr.mnthly.evaluation.tree</field>
        <field name="model">hr.mnthly.evaluation</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Monthly Evaluation" >

                    <field name="employee_id" width="300" on_change="onchange_employee(employee_id)" required="1"/>
                     <field name="department_id" width="300"/> 
                     <field name="name" width="300"/> 
                     <field name="state" string="Status" width="300"/>

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>


     <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="appraisals_to_acknowledge">
            <field name="name">Appraisals to acknowledge</field>
            <field name="res_model">hr.mnthly.evaluation</field>
            <field name="view_type">tree</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
<!--             <field name="context">{'search_default_out_emp':1}</field>  -->
<!--             <field name="domain">[('state','in',('confirm','validate1','validate'))]</field> -->
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_hr_mnthly_evaluation_submitted_tree"/>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_hr_mnthly_evaluation_search"/>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@odoo(OpenERP) Tree View:

you should change action in view_type and view_mode then after tree view show correctly.

```
          <record id="appraisals_to_acknowledge" model="ir.actions.act_window">
                <field name="name">Appraisals to acknowledge</field>
                <field name="res_model">hr.mnthly.evaluation</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">tree,form,search</field>
                <field name="context">{}</field>
          </record>
```